# Duda con activeMQ e hilos

Tags: java, spring, hilos, activemq

Estoy creando una aplicación Spring que envía y recibe mensajes de una cola con activeMQ, el proyecto por ahora funciona correctamente, El problema es que me han dicho que la aplicacion debe tener un pool de consumidores de la cola y no sé como implementarlo.

Esta es la clase consumidora y que actualmente funciona:

```
@Component
public class ConsumerColaAndroid {
    
    
    @JmsListener(destination = "colaAndroid")
    public void receiveMessage(String dato) {
        System.out.println("mensaje recibido consumidor cola android <" + dato + ">");
        
    }
}
```

He estado buscando información en internet sobre un pool de hilos y parece sencillo, pero no sé como implementar el pool de hilos con el consumidor, ya que un hilo tiene una función run(), por lo que no sabría donde colocar el **@JmsListener** y el **(String dato)**. ¿Cómo podría encajar ambas cosas en la clase ConsumerColaAndroid?

Por otro lado al ser una aplicación Spring con su application, controller, service ¿Dónde iría el Thread pool?, ¿En el application?

el código del application es el siguiente:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GestionColasApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GestionColasApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano y saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @FireStarter JMS ya tiene la funcionalidad de ejecutar `hilos` o `trabajadores(workers)` la forma más simple de lograrlo es utilizando la propiedad `concurrency`, por ejemplo según tú código si queremos 5 trabajadores en la cola seria de la siguiente forma:

```
@Component
public class ConsumerColaAndroid {        
    
    @JmsListener(destination = "colaAndroid", concurrency = "5")
    public void receiveMessage(String dato) {
        System.out.println("mensaje recibido consumidor cola android <" + dato + ">");
        
    }
}
```

Si quieres una configuración global para todos los `JmsListener` según la documentación de Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("5");
        return factory;
    }
}
```

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#remoting-jms

Comment: Hola Roberto! muchas gracias por la información, lo probaré ahora mismo. Muchas gracias!